# How to adjust spacing of underlined text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

Anyone know how to do this? Right now when zoomed out at 100%, the underline looks a little too close to the text. I'm using the latest version of Illustrator.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not move position of the underline vertically if using the underline feature for text.

Your best bet is to manually underline the text by drawing your own path if you aren't happy with the automatic underline.